# Disappearing nav links/bars

Tags: html, css, navigation, wrapper

I have searched the site extensively but cannot find the answer. Please I am a newbie and I need your help.

I want to create a fixed navigation bar yet each time a fixed rule is placed inside my css style sheet the navigation bar disappears. Here is my html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
```

and here is jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/ePttq/

any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: I figure you also need to explain what a Fixed Rule is ? And, since you're a newbie, you're doing a great job. Go easy on yourself! People are here to help :)

Comment: `yet each time a fixed rule is placed inside my css style sheet the navigation bar disappears` -- Can you elaborate this part? and also explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can't see the problem...

Comment: thank you everyone for getting back to me! I really appreciate it very much.  By fixed rule I mean the "position: fixed" tag that is used in CSS. I apologize if I am not using the right terms but I am still learning. Once again, thank you all for getting back to me.

Comment: just added an answer...hoping you've struck gold here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem of `z-index` in `#nav` write this style to the `#nav`

```
#container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:50px;
}

#nav {
    height: 50px;
    background: #b7d84b;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    width:900px;
    top:0;
}
```

updated [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/ePttq/4/)

Comment: I have updated the answer as well as jsFiddle code, hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay..there's your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ePttq/3/

And here's the change you need to make in your css:

```
#nav {
    height: 50px;
    background: #b7d84b;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:100;
    right:0px;
}
```

I have made your navbar fixed...Even on scrolling..this will continue to work :)

Comment: Hope you do not mind my asking but how did you figure out that I needed to add "z-index:100"?

Comment: I'd ideally set it to 9999..if my page contains many many elements. It will always work, then. But, 100 or so is good in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use following inline style in your nav div:

```
<div id="nav" style="position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;z-index:10000">
            <a href="#">Link1</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
height: 50px;
background: #b7d84b;
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
width:100%;
}
```